# Linked Transactions for PurchaseOrders and Bills not showing up in API

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

According to the [documentation](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/purchaseorder), `LinkedTxns` should be returned with both `PurchaseOrders` and `Bills`.

But, that feature does not appear to be working.

For example, this is the XML returned for the `PurchaseOrder` with `DocNumber` 1005.

```
<PurchaseOrder>
  <Id>97</Id>
  <SyncToken>6</SyncToken>
  <MetaData>
    <CreateTime>2014-06-24T16:21:18-0400</CreateTime>
    <LastUpdatedTime>2014-06-25T10:42:03-0400</LastUpdatedTime>
  </MetaData>
  <DocNumber>1005</DocNumber>
  <TxnDate>2014-06-24</TxnDate>
  <PrivateNote>...</PrivateNote>
  <Line>
    <Id>7</Id>
    <Amount>1600.0</Amount>
    <DetailType>ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail</DetailType>
    <ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail>
      <ItemRef name="Transportation">21</ItemRef>
      <UnitPrice>1600.0</UnitPrice>
      <Qty>1.0</Qty>
      <TaxCodeRef>NON</TaxCodeRef>
      <BillableStatus>NotBillable</BillableStatus>
    </ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail>
  </Line>
  <VendorRef name="...">3</VendorRef>
  <APAccountRef name="Accounts Payable">51</APAccountRef>
  <TotalAmt>1600.0</TotalAmt>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

And here is the screen shot from Quickbooks Online that shows that the linked transaction exists.

[image: Quickbooks Online Evidence]

Is there a workaround for this problem? Is it caused by something that I can address?

Answer (score 0):

LinkedTxn's are not supported for Bills at the time of this writing.

References:
See issue QBO-34591 on the following link:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq/qbo_v3_known_issues

Answer (score 0):

According to the release notes at https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0000_about_intuit_developer/0080_release_notes/quickbooks_api_release_notes  This should have been addressed now.